# Pivot table with date, variable categories and sum values in php sql

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table, categories

I would like to create pivot table of expenses from SQL select in PHP in which dates will be rows, categories will by data columns and sum of all expencies in date certain day and category will be table data.

Raw data are stored in SQL table:

```
ID - DATE - CATEGORY - CAT. NAME - PRICE
01 - 1/01 - 1        - CAR       - 5
02 - 1/01 - 2        - FOOD      - 10
03 - 1/02 - 2        - FOOD      - 10
04 - 1/02 - 2        - FOOD      - 10
05 - 1/02 - 4        - HOUSE     - 50
06 - 1/02 - 1        - CAR       - 5
07 - 1/03 - 1        - CAR       - 5
08 - 1/03 - 2        - FOOD      - 10
09 - 1/03 - 2        - FOOD      - 10
10 - 1/03 - 3        - DOG       - 20
```

It is table of expenses. Not every day has filled every category.

I use another table for storeing table names for category ids.

I fetch SQL request:

```
SELECT E.expense_date, C.id_category, C.category_name, SUM(E.price) AS price
FROM expenses E, expenses_category C
WHERE E.category = C.id_category
GROUP BY E.expense_date, C.category_name
ORDER BY E.expense_date ASC, C.category_name, E.price ASC
```

Result of SQL request looks similar to this:

```
DATE - CAT. NAME - SUM
1/01 - CAR       - 5
1/01 - FOOD      - 10
1/02 - CAR       - 5
1/02 - FOOD      - 20
1/02 - HOUSE     - 50
1/01 - CAR       - 5
1/01 - FOOD      - 20
1/01 - DOG       - 20
```

But I would like to transfer SQL select to pivot table where rows will be dates, data columns will be categories and table datas will be sum of expenses. Like this:

```
      CAR / FOOD / DOG / HOUSE / DAY
1/01   5     10     X     X      25
1/02   5     20     X    50      65
1/03   5     20    20     X      45
SUM   15     50    20    50     135
```

I have thinking about this problem around a month now and googled answers for last 6 hours. Unfortunately my skills are not sufficient for solving the case and for creating correct PHP code :{

I tried several approaches, non was sucessfull. I know only procedural coding, OOP is beyound my knowleadge.

All information/tutorials I have found focus only on finit amouth of categories while I try to create code which will create number of table columns based on number of categories which were retrieved (understand infinit).

Can anybody help me design PHP code for retrieving pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Considered your database result `$result` is a **Traversable** and the fetch-mode you have is assoc:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
   $table[$row["expense_date"]][$row["category_name"]] = $row["price"];
}
```

Before a new *expense date* you can also initialize all category fields with `"X"` to have them already in the `$table` array or you do that on the fly when you output the table on unset fields in the matrix.

Same of the summary column, you need to create the sum (or you do that within your SQL query already, should be possible with a `UNION`).

Comment: not working for me, i have the same problem as the problem starter:

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array